# Проблема с наследованием в шаблоне Django

Tags: python, django

Столкнулся с проблемой наследования и отображения содержимого блога.
А именно. Обучаюсь по книге Антонио Меле "Django на примерах".
По упражнению первой главы оформил и проверил досокнально десяток раз файлы *.py и шаблоны .html. Сравнил с оф.репозиторием книги - не работает, скопировал код из репозитория - не работает, скачал английскую версию книги - все один к одному - не работает.
Блог наполнен пятью постами. Но список постов по адресу 127.0.0.1:8000/blog/ не отображается. 
Браузер Mozilla Firefox, OS Linux Mint.
Не знаю что делать, стою на месте третий день. 
Буду очень благодарен.
 [Мой код расположен по этому адресу](https://github.com/Stanlyzoolo/For-study/tree/master/mysite)
[image: Пример вывода]

Comment: Вы в админке добавляете посты? Указываете ли Status: Published при создании?

Comment: Да, посты я добавлял в админке, но статус стоял Draft, а не Published.
Как только изменил статус, отобразились все посты.Спасибо, Вам, за помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запустил у себя. Книгу не читал, поэтому пошагово до момента начала корректной работы:

1. Описка - файл заканчивается на `.py.` (с точкой) - For-study/mysite/blog/models.py.
2. `Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '0.0.0.0:8000'. You may need to add '0.0.0.0' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.`

Добавляем в разрешенные хосты:

mysite/mysite/settings.py

`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ('0.0.0.0',)`

3. Создаем таблицы:
   `python manage.py migrate`
4. Не хватает пустых файлов `__init__.py` в `blog/` и `migrations/`, добавить.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
5. [Andrey](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/213678/andrey) верно пишет - необходимо в админке добавить посты со статусом Published. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
6. Работает.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо Вам за отзывчивость.
Я прошелся в коде по всем замечаниям, ALLOWED_HOSTS не трогал.
Для чего добавлять туда значения, там установлен пустой список [ ]. И необходимая часть блога работает, пока.

Проблема была в админке. Не знаю как я споткнулся на ровном месте. 
Спасибо за подробный разбор!)